# How can iRender the dynamic components without changing the static ones using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have page setup as follows[image]

The red color areas are static one and green color area is the dynamic one. In the side bar there is a navigation panel.When user click on a button in the navigation bar i want to update the green colored area without re rendering the red colored static area.How can i achieve this.

Note that I am developing this using react native and i want a solution that can apply on react native project too.

Please give me  a solution in detailed

Thankyou

Answer (score -1):

for example

```
<div className={styles.wrapper}>
   <div>Navigation</div>
   <div>{children}</div>
   <div>Footer</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code to me.I coudn't able to figure out how to implement this in my code